# How can I set one style to override another conflicting style in CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts, lamp

I'm displaying links that get marked as read in a database when a user clicks them. I want to style the clicked and unclicked links based on the database information not the user's browser history. So far, when I use:

```
 10 a:visited {
 11   color: #444;
 12 }
 13
 14 a:link {
 15   font-weight: bold;
 16   color:black;
 17 }
 18
 19 .read {
 20   color: #444!important;
 21 }
 22
 23 .unread {
 24   font-weight: bold!important;
 25   color:black!important;
 26 }
```

and

```
<tr class="even">
  <td><a class="read" href="example.com">blah</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
  <td><a class="unread" href="example.org">foo</a></td>
</tr>
```

and a link has been visited, but not from this page (it's still marked as unread in the database), I get weird results. For example only the color will work, but the weight won't, etc.

Is it possible to have one style override another when they conflict?

Thanks!

EDIT: updated code to clarify

### Solution

```
 10 a:link,
 11 a:visited {
 12   font-weight: bold;
 13   color: black;
 14 }
 15
 16 a.read {
 17   color: #444;
 18   font-weight: lighter !important; /* omission or even "normal" didn't work here. */
 19 }
 20
 21 a.unread {
 22   font-weight: bold !important;
 23   color: black !important;
 24 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, if you don't want the browsers own history to interfere with your styles then use the :visited pseudo-class to match the style of the non-visited link, then just apply classes manually based on your DB records.

Regarding conflicting styles, it's all about the [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) of the selector, and if two with the same properties conflict (have the same specificity) the last one "wins".

**Do this:**

```
a:link, 
a:visited {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

a.read {
    color: #444;
}
```

Comment: thanks. i tweaked it a little (see edit above), but this was basically what did it. I had to explicitly use "lighter". ...weird

Comment: Not too sure why "normal" wouldn't work, weird. You shouldn't need !important on your font-weight property as the selector has a higher specificity. And you don't really need the "unread" class at all. Omitting the "read" class from the element will have the same effect.

Answer (score 39):

You can use the !important directive.  eg.

```
.myClass
{
   color:red !important;
   background-color:white !important;
}
```

Place !important after each style as shown above when you need to override any other styles also being applied.

Comment: I updated the code in the question. !important doesn't change the results. Thanks though!

Comment: No problems.  I think web browser support for styling anchor tags using pseudo selectors varies.  Have you tried it in different browsers?

Comment: How do I override something that already has `!important` on it?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a.unread, a:visited.unread {style 1}

a.read, a:visited.read {style 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

One, check your HTML to make sure `class="read"` and `class="unread"` are being added to your links.

Two, try adding `a` in your `.read` and `.unread` CSS rules:

```
a.read { /* ... */ }
a.unread { /* ... */ }
```

If that doesn't work, try adding a space before `!important`.  I don't think this is required, but [most examples I have seen](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) include it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define specificity of your CSS selectors.

`a { /* style 1 */ }`

would be overridden by

`div a { /* style 2 */ }`

where `div` is a parent element of `a`

More details can be found on [Selectutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/advanced_conflict.htm).