# display:none; not working but visibility:hidden; does

Tags: css, visibility, display

I'm trying to hide my menu when the screen is a certain width but for some reason `display:none` doesnt work but `visibility:hidden` does.
 I'm using the exact code of the person in the tutorial (taken from his uploaded `css` file) and it works for him but not for me?
 I understand the difference between the two but I dont understand why one hides the element but the other doesn't for some reason.
This is the `css` code:

```
  .site-header__menu-trigger {
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 7px;
    right: 46px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 530px) {

    .site-header__menu-trigger {
      top: 5px;
      font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 960px) {

    .site-header__menu-trigger {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

Update: Sorry here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>
<header class="site-header">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="school-logo-text float-left"><a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>"><strong>Fictional</strong> University</a></h1>
      <span class="js-search-trigger site-header__search-trigger"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <i class="site-header__menu-trigger fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      <div class="site-header__menu group">
        <nav class="main-navigation">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/about-us') ?>">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/programs') ?>">Programs</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/events') ?>">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/campuses') ?>">Campuses</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/blog') ?>">Blog</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="site-header__util">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn--small btn--orange float-left push-right">Login</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn--small  btn--dark-orange float-left">Sign Up</a>
          <span class="search-trigger js-search-trigger"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Update 2: Changing the order of my wp_enqueue_style() functions fixed the problem, I had to first load the bootstrap css and then my own css file like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style('fontAwesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style('university_main_styles', get_stylesheet_uri(), NULL, microtime());
```

Now it even works without the !important behind display.

Comment: Can you provide a working example? In a code snippet (here at stackoverflow) or maybe some online sandox (like jsfiddle for example)

Comment: please show your html

Comment: Show us your complete code, we can't help u if you do not provide your full code.

Comment: Do you use a library like bootstrap or else ? Probably the library css applies a !important rule on 'display' property of your element. That would explain why visibility works.

Comment: try  `display: none!important;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set one style to override another conflicting style in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549828/how-can-i-set-one-style-to-override-another-conflicting-style-in-css)

Comment: Just for your information: this site is the part of web, it uses web technologies to work. Your task relies purely on web technologies too. That means there's no need for us to take your code and paste it in some sandbox, you can easily create a working example yourself; it will really increase chance of getting help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only reason for `display: none;` not to be working is, if it's overwritten by other CSS with higher precedence.

Check if you are using a CSS library like `Bootstrap` or `TailwindCSS` that could be overwriting your `display: none;` rule.

If you need to retain using those libraries, you can try using the `!important` property like this: `display: none !important;`

**Edit:**

After looking at your HTML my initial presumption proved to be true.
The Font Awesome class `fa` has an inline property `display: inline-block;` that overwrites your `display` property.

Comment: This works fine thank you! I'm using font awesome for the menu, could that cause this problem?

Comment: @Rugo yes, that's the reason. Please have a look at my edit.

Comment: wow, already +8 on this answer ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!

```css
.site-header__menu-trigger {
      display: none !important;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code is working for me, the problem could be that you don't have the library that he is using for icons (FONTAWESOME), try to write inside `<i class="site-header__menu-trigger fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true">Hello</i>` Do you see it?
If you see Hello that's mean that you need to import fontawesome, go here `https://fontawesome.com/start` to see how to do that